# Rotate the view only in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, cgaffinetransform, screen-rotation

My application is only supported on Portrait mode. I have requirement that need to rotate the particular `UIView` only according to the device orientation.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by UIView alone?

Comment: view only... not a viewController

Comment: Do you need to rotate the view, when your device orientation changes?

Comment: yes. I have to change particular view according to the device orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the long try I found the answer using `CGAffineTransform` ..

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //Obtain current device orientation
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    CGFloat angle;
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            angle = M_PI;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = - M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        default:
            angle = 0.f;
            break;
    }
    animationView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    animationView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below give code in your viewdidload or init

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:   @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

In deviceOrientationDidChange function you will get the device orientation,according to this you can update your view

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //Obtain current device orientation
     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

      //Do my thing
 }
```

Comment: thanks. This I have done. I need to rotate the view according to the device orientation.

Comment: @YanoRatheez: CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[yourView setTransform:transform];
Here set angle corresponding to your device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    // set your view frame work for portrait mode

}
else {
// set new frame of view for landscape mode.
}
```

Hope you get the idea.
thanks

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get this.. I have to rotate the view only using CGAffineTransform or some other.